# CSS/HTML How To Display Form Data On A Specific Spot On The Web Page

Tags: php, html, css, forms, alignment

I have a web page which displays data on the left side of the page and it goes down in a list.

I need help displaying a form in the middle/right side of the page using CSS. With the current CSS I have for the form, it is displayed at the bottom of the page which is wrong, I want it to be in the middle/right. The form is basically a search field where users can search for members on the website.

I'm bad with CSS, maybe someone can also suggest a cool style for the form? :D

The div class called searchList is where the form is that I want to align to the middle/right

My code:

```
<?php
include('init.inc.php');

$output = '';

if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];
    $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq); //filter, can remove

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_first LIKE '%$searchq%' OR user_last LIKE '%$searchq%' OR user_uid LIKE '%$searchq%'");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($count == 0){
        $output = 'There was no search found!';
    }else{
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $uname = $row['user_uid'];
            $fname = $row['user_first'];
            $lname = $row['user_last'];
            $email = $row['user_email'];
            $id = $row['user_id'];

            $output .= '<div> '.$uname.' '.$fname.' '.$lname.' '.$email.'</div>';
        }
    }

}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C/DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
     <section id="showcase1">
        <section id="newsletter">
          <div class="container">
             <h1>ProjectNet Members:</h1>
          </div>
        </section>
        <div class="container">
           <div class="userList">
            <?php
               foreach (fetch_users() as $user){
                ?>
                <p>
                    <button><a class="userList" href="profile.php?uid=<?php echo $user['id']; ?>"><?php echo $user['username']; ?></a></button>
                </p>
                <?php

               }
            ?>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="searchList">
           <form id="search" action="user_list.php" method="post">
               <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for members..." />
               <input type="submit" value="Search" />
           </form>
           <?php print("$output");?>
       </div>
    </section>
  </body> 
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.searchList {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font: 20px Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif;
    text-align: center;

}
```

UPDATE:
I managed to get the form in the middle of the screen, I need help moving it slightly towards the right.

CSS:

```
.searchList {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font: 19px Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 35px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: -100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    float: right;
}


#search input[type="submit"] {
    cursor: pointer;

    border: none;
    background: #fafafa;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font: Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif;
}
#search input[type="text"] {
    width: 18%;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    background: #FFF;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 4px;
}
}
#search input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: #e8491d;
    color: #fafafa;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Look into [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com). It is a html/css framework to help with page layout and common elements

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS position property or float property.
To display form on the right of the page use `float : right;`

```
form {
 float : right;
}
```

Comment: That did not work for me, I've managed to get the form to stay in the middle now, would you know how to move it slightly towards the right? I've updated my post above to include the new CSS code :)

Answer (score 0):

Moving to the right, where the 4th value is the left padding.
padding: 0px 0px 0px 30px;
..alternatively you can use.
padding-left: 30px;

If you want to have better control of the layout structure I suggest you use "grid" which is embedded in css. Search for "css grid".